# php variable using mongodb not showing on website server

Tags: php, mongodb

i am making a twitter clone website using php, and this is the script for creating a tweet:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 require_once('twitterdbconnect.php');

 if(!isset($_POST['body'])) { //see if the post variable has the body of our tweet
  exit;
 }
 
 $user_id = $_SESSION['user']; //if there is a tweet get the users id from session
 $userData = $db->users->findOne( array('_id'=>$user_id));  //get the users data by asking the database for this user
 $body = substr($_POST['body'], 140); //body is the first 140 characters of the post
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 
 $db->tweets->insertOne( array(         //create a tweets collection and send the tweet there
    'authorId' => $user_id,
    'authorName' => $userData['username'], 
    'body' => $body,
    'created' => $date

    ));
    
header('Location: home.php');
?>
```

this is the script of printing it on the home page:

```
<div>
<?php 
    $recent_tweets = get_recent_tweets($db);
    foreach($recent_tweets as $tweet) {
        echo '<p><a href="profile.php?id=' . $tweet['authorId'] . '">' . $tweet['authorName'] .'</a></p>';
        echo '<p>' . $tweet['body'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $tweet['created'] . '</p>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
 ?>
</div>
```

the other variables seem to work, but the body variable does not show up and the end result is so:

[image]

How can I make it appear as so:

[image]
?

Comment: Can we see `get_recent_tweets`?

Comment: @Joe `function get_recent_tweets($db) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $result = $db->tweets->find( array('authorId' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("$id")));
  $recent_tweets = iterator_to_array($result);
  return $recent_tweets;
 }`

Comment: Try using `var_dump` or `print_r` to output `$recent_tweets` so you cans see what was returned.

Comment: @Joe interesting, it returns `$tweet['body']`  as  `string(0) "" `